# Can I override the custom errors of an mvc area using the web.config in the view folder/

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-config

I have an area in my Mvc solution called /Admin

Within the /Admin/Views folder there is a standard web.config file.

I have included in this config file a customerErrors element under the system.web:

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/admin/oops" >  
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/admin/pagenotfound"/>
</customErrors>
```

Which differs from the one in my root web.config.

My expectation was that this would give me specific control of how errors are dealt with in the admin area.

This isn't working.

Am I taking crazy pills or should I be able to override the default web.config settings with a more specific one in the area's web.config?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually here is an article written about areas in mvc.

[AREAS in ASP.NET MVC](http://mstechkb.blogspot.in/2010/10/areas-in-aspnet-mvc-20.html)

According to this article, we cannot override the settings..

> Web.Config in Views folder
>   Pages also called views are available in the views folder. In MVC views are not directly exposed to outside by URLS. All the view requests should go to the controller and it will render the exact view using the inputs from URL. Views are normal asp.net web pages, so they can be accessible a URL. To restrict direct accessing of views, we use web.config file in views folder. The web.config has a default handler mapping to blocks all the pages which has extension ASPX.
>
> Web.Config in Area folder
>   Similarly for views, there is a web.config file for each area serving the same purpose. This is to restrict access of ASPX files. If we don't want to restrict them at area Level, we can delete this web.Config file.
>
> **Application settings in Web.Config**
>   There are many web.config files; can we have application settings of areas in area specific web.config file? The answer is No, we cannot or have or override the appsettings configurations. All the application settings should be defined in the web.config of the root folder