# .Net MVC 4 appSettings conflict with area web.config files

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, web-config

I am working on a .Net MVC 4 project and am having some issues with the appSettings in the web.config file. I have a value set in the root web.config (ProjectName/web.config). I also have created an Area, and I am attempting to override the root value in a local web.config (ProjectName/AreaName/Views/web.config). In the Controller of my Area, I am setting a ViewBag value by pulling from the appSetting value, then in the View I'm displaying the ViewBag value. Pretty simple stuff, and it works fine, except that the Area appSetting value is not overriding the root appSetting value.

I have noticed that if I move the root appSetting from ProjectName/web.config to ProjectName/Views/web.config, no value comes through at all. After discovering this, I tried to create a new web.config at the root of the Area (ProjectName/AreaName/web.config) and moved my Area appSetting from ProjectName/AreaName/Views/web.config to ProjectName/AreaName/web.config. However, the root appSetting value still came through instead of the Area value.

Does anyone have any idea why this is? This is the opposite behavior I am used to in ASP.Net web forms, where appSettings in any subordinate web.config files will override the values set in the root web.config. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I override the custom errors of an mvc area using the web.config in the view folder/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14452214/can-i-override-the-custom-errors-of-an-mvc-area-using-the-web-config-in-the-view)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14452214/can-i-override-the-custom-errors-of-an-mvc-area-using-the-web-config-in-the-view). Apparently Area web.config settings do not override root web.config settings. That is unfortunate.